# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 13,Token in error = Order ]

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

Table name is `Order`. And `OrderID` is its column name.Every time I run it I get the exception

```
" There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 13,
Token in error = Order ]"
```

Please help me . Thank you.The Columns names are similar as given by the code.

```
Int32 Product_ID = Convert.ToInt32(TxtProductId.Text);
Int64 Order_ID = Convert.ToInt32(TxtOrderNo.Text);
Int64 MoneyLeft = new int();
Int64 MoneyGiven = Convert.ToInt32(TxtAdvance.Text);
Int64 TotalMoney = Convert.ToInt32(LblTotalPrice.Text);
//Calculate Money left
MoneyLeft=TotalMoney-MoneyGiven;
string query = "INSERT INTO ORDER
(
    OrderId,
    OrderName,
    OrderItemNo,
    OrderQuantity,
    OrderMoneyLeft,
    OrderMoneyGiven,
    OrderTotalMoney
  )
VALUES
  (
    @val1,
    @val2,
    @val3,
    @val4,
    @val5,
    @val6,
    @val7
  )";

Command.Connection = SQLConnection;
Command.CommandText = query;
Command.Parameters.Clear();
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", Order_ID);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", TxtCustomerName.Text);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", Product_ID);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", TxtItemQuantity.Text.ToString());
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val5", MoneyLeft);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val6",MoneyGiven);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val7", TotalMoney);
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I see, `ORDER` is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in T-SQL. You should use it with square brackets like `[ORDER]`. The best solution is to change your table name to a *non-reserved* word.

But in such a case, I'm surprised that you didn't get any *Incorrect syntax near..* type of error.

Other than that, we need to know what is your column types and what is your parameter values exactly. I strongly suspect about `OrderQuantity` column. Based on it's name, it sounds like a numerical typed column. But you passed a string as a parameter.

And don't use `AddWithValue` method. It might generate unexpected results. Use [`.Add()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx) and it's overloads. Don't forget to use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SQLConnection` and `SqlCommand` as well.

Read: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I have changed the OrderQuantity coloumn type with int. I have used the [Order].Now i am using .Add() and its overloads. Now i am getting the error " The column cannot be modified. [ Column name = OrderId ]"

Comment: Thank you very much Soner Gonul :) The problem was solved by using [] around Order. i have solved it , I had autoincremented the OrderId due to which i faced the " The column cannot be modified. [ Column name = OrderId ]".